# Match line by line and replace data

Tags: python

I have two files. File1 with data

```
ND2D1BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n1),.A2(),.ZN(n2)); |2
GAO21D1BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n2),.A2(),.B(),.Z(n3)); |4
CKLHQD14BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.CPN(#),.E(1),.TE(n3),.Q(n4)); |5
ND3OPTPAD6BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n4),.A2(),.A3(),.ZN(n5)); |8
AN4D2BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n5),.A2(),.A3(),.A4(),.Z(n6)); |11
```

And file2 with data

```
NR2SKRD12BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n7),.A2(),.ZN(n8)); |2
MUX2D2BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I0(n8),.I1(),.S(),.Z(n9)); |4
CKLHQD16BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.CPN(#),.E(1),.TE(n9),.Q(n10)); |5
LHCSNQD1BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.CDN(n10),.D(),.E(1),.SDN(),.Q(n11)); |6
OAI21D8BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n11),.A2(),.B(),.ZN(n12)); |9
DCCKND16BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(n12),.ZN(n13)); |10
INVSKFD14BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(n13),.ZN(n14)); |11
```

I want to compare `last digit i.e digit after |` of `file1` with `file2` and if the digit matches, I want to replace `first ()` in match line in file2 with `(n) value`  in file1.

I wrote the code

```
x1="(n"
x2=")"
with open('file1','r') as fin: 
 for line in fin: 
   l= line[-4:] 
   z1=line.find(x1) 
   z2=line.find(x2) 
   l1=line[z1:z2] 
   print l1 
   fout =open('file2','r+') 
   for line2 in fout: 
       if "()" in line2: 
           k=line2[-4:] 
              if l==k: 
                 l=line2.replace("()",l1+")",1) 
                 fout.write(l)
```

The code works well but the only problem i am getting is , if last digit matches, it is not replacing the match line in file2 but adding the match line in new line at end in file2.

Output i am getting is

```
NR2SKRD12BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n7),.A2(),.ZN(n8)); |2
MUX2D2BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I0(n8),.I1(),.S(),.Z(n9)); |4
CKLHQD16BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.CPN(#),.E(1),.TE(n9),.Q(n10)); |5
LHCSNQD1BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.CDN(n10),.D(),.E(1),.SDN(),.Q(n11)); |6
OAI21D8BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n11),.A2(),.B(),.ZN(n12)); |9
DCCKND16BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(n12),.ZN(n13)); |10
INVSKFD14BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(n13),.ZN(n14)); |11
NR2SKRD12BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n7),.A2(n1),.ZN(n8)); |2
MUX2D2BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I0(n8),.I1(n2),.S(),.Z(n9)); |4
```

Output I want is

```
NR2SKRD12BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n7),.A2(n1),.ZN(n8)); |2
MUX2D2BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I0(n8),.I1(n2),.S(),.Z(n9)); |4
CKLHQD16BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.CPN(#),.E(1),.TE(n9),.Q(n10)); |5
LHCSNQD1BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.CDN(n10),.D(),.E(1),.SDN(),.Q(n11)); |6
OAI21D8BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.A1(n11),.A2(),.B(),.ZN(n12)); |9
DCCKND16BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(n12),.ZN(n13)); |10
INVSKFD14BWP210H6P51CNODSVT-(.I(n13),.ZN(n14)); |11
```

Comment: There is no (n1) value in any of the files. And you want "(.A1(n7),.A2(n1),.ZN(n8))"

Comment: What i want is .. ```compare last digit of file1 and file2 if they matches, replace file2 first () with (n) value from file1```. The code i wrote works fine but only problem I am getting is, when match it is adding the line in new line at end in file2, but I want the line to be replaced in file2.

Comment: So where is this (n1) coming from?

Comment: (n1) is there in file1 ```.A1(n1)```

Comment: I want to replace first (n) value from file1 in file2 ```first ()``` in the match line.

Comment: z1=line.find(x1) 
   z2=line.find(x2) 

Where are those x1 and x2 var from in your code?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention ```x1, x2```. Modified the code in above question. You can check